# How to get data from a public form and update the salesforce leads?

Tags: lightning, rest-api, leads, form, updaterecord

I am trying to achieve this:

> 1. Create a public form
> 2. Send this form to the customer via email
> 3. Customer opens the form and fill in the required fields
> 4. Get the required field and update the salesforce lead
> 5. If possible, first convert the form data into a pdf file and attach this file to the salesforce leads attachment by ID using REST
>    API.

but i don't know how to achieve this, any solution or suggestions, please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Having done something like this recently, I would do the following:

- Create an Experience site (or use an existing one)
- Create a new page on that site; note the page's URL
- Add a screen flow component that collects user data and does steps 4 and 5.   You'll need to escape to Apex to do the PDF generation
- Use SF automation to send an email to customer with link to the Experience site's page

Because a Guest user is involved, you'll need to think carefully about how to grant permissions to the Flow so it can execute for the Guest user and be able to update the Lead and File